# Хеш функция Дженкинса

Tags: delphi, хеширование

В Delphi XE2 портировали функцию вычисления хеша по Дженкинсу (модуль System.Generics.Defaults.pas)

```
function BobJenkinsHash(const Data; Len, InitData: Integer): Integer;
```

Оригинал находится [здесь](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup3.c).
Мне же понадобилась [версия для вычисления 64-битного хеша](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup8.c).
Но почему-то у меня не взлетела - вычисляет хэши странным образом:
то разные значения для одних и тех же данных, то один и тот же хэш для разных данных.
Прошу совета у знающих, где я мог ошибиться. С уважением.

```
{ BobJenkinsHash64 }
// http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup8.c

procedure mix64(var a, b, c: UInt64); inline;
begin
  Dec(a, b); Dec(a, c); a := a xor (c shr 43);
  Dec(b, c); Dec(b, a); b := b xor (a shl  9);
  Dec(c, a); Dec(c, b); c := c xor (b shr  8);
  Dec(a, b); Dec(a, c); a := a xor (c shr 38);
  Dec(b, c); Dec(b, a); b := b xor (a shl 23);
  Dec(c, a); Dec(c, b); c := c xor (b shr  5);
  Dec(a, b); Dec(a, c); a := a xor (c shr 35);
  Dec(b, c); Dec(b, a); b := b xor (a shl 49);
  Dec(c, a); Dec(c, b); c := c xor (b shr 11);
  Dec(a, b); Dec(a, c); a := a xor (c shr 12);
  Dec(b, c); Dec(b, a); b := b xor (a shl 18);
  Dec(c, a); Dec(c, b); c := c xor (b shr 22);
end;

{$POINTERMATH ON}

function BobJenkinsHash64(const k; length, level: Integer): UInt64;
var
  pb: PByte;
  pd: PUInt64 absolute pb;
  a, b, c, len: UInt64;
begin
  len := length;
  a := level;
  b := level;
  c := $9e3779b97f4a7c13;
  pb := @k;
  while len >= 24 do
  begin
    a := a + pd[0]  + (pd[ 1] shl 8) + (pd[ 2] shl 16) + (pd[ 3] shl 24) + (pd[ 4] shl 32) + (pd[ 5] shl 40) + (pd[ 6] shl 48) + (pd[ 7] shl 56);
    b := b + pd[8]  + (pd[ 9] shl 8) + (pd[10] shl 16) + (pd[11] shl 24) + (pd[12] shl 32) + (pd[13] shl 40) + (pd[14] shl 48) + (pd[15] shl 56);
    c := c + pd[16] + (pd[17] shl 8) + (pd[18] shl 16) + (pd[19] shl 24) + (pd[20] shl 32) + (pd[21] shl 40) + (pd[22] shl 48) + (pd[23] shl 56);
    mix64(a, b, c);
    Inc(pb, 24);
    Dec(Len, 24);
  end;
  Inc(c, length);
  case len of
    23: Inc(c, (pd[22] shl 56));
    22: Inc(c, (pd[21] shl 48));
    21: Inc(c, (pd[20] shl 40));
    20: Inc(c, (pd[19] shl 32));
    19: Inc(c, (pd[18] shl 24));
    18: Inc(c, (pd[17] shl 16));
    17: Inc(c, (pd[16] shl  8));
    16: Inc(b, (pd[15] shl 56));
    15: Inc(b, (pd[14] shl 48));
    14: Inc(b, (pd[13] shl 40));
    13: Inc(b, (pd[12] shl 32));
    12: Inc(b, (pd[11] shl 24));
    11: Inc(b, (pd[10] shl 16));
    10: Inc(b, (pd[ 9] shl  8));
     9: Inc(b, (pd[ 8]));
     8: Inc(a, (pd[ 7] shl 56));
     7: Inc(a, (pd[ 6] shl 48));
     6: Inc(a, (pd[ 5] shl 40));
     5: Inc(a, (pd[ 4] shl 32));
     4: Inc(a, (pd[ 3] shl 24));
     3: Inc(a, (pd[ 2] shl 16));
     2: Inc(a, (pd[ 1] shl  8));
     1: Inc(a, (pd[ 0]));
     0: ;
  end;
  mix64(a, b, c);
  Result := c;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyMSG: string;
begin
  MyMSG := Edit1.Text;
  Edit2.Text := IntToStr(BobJenkinsHash64(MyMSG, Length(MyMSG) * SizeOf(MyMSG[1]), 13));
end;
```

Comment: На вход подается массив байтов.
Пока попробую вариант предложенный @Sh4dow, но придется подумать о переобразовании массива байтов в массив UInt64.
Вполне возможно что я и путаю pb и pd, или еще что другое, так как опыта работы с памятью и ссылками маловато, да С++, к своему стыду, знаю постольку-поскольку.
Для тех, кто хочет посмотреть как разработчики Delphi портировали 32-битную версую, привожу ее исходный код:
http://narod.ru/disk/25853859001/System.Generics.Defaults.pas.html

Comment: Я ответ обновил, пробуйте. Там для делфи7, но работать должно.

Comment: @toxicdream, приятно, но лучше нажмите галку рядом с ответом =)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. В итоге всех размышлении, решил-таки отказать от этой функции в пользу MaHash8v64. Хеш функция Дженкинса дает много (кажется, хотя может это только у меня так) коллизии.
Edit1=Edit2
012345678901234567890122=012345678901234567890123

Comment: Ну 64 бита для хэша - вообще довольно мало, хотя для малых объемов данных мб и приемлемо.

Comment: @toxicdream а проверьте еще раз?) Присмотрелся к коллизии, нашел ошибку. (обновил ответ)

*ЗЫ* я так понял, он нормально работает с данными > 24 байт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все закрываю вопрос.
Ошибка была здесь
вместо

```
pb := @k;
```

надо было

```
pb := @(k[0]);
```

Всем спасибо, пошел учить мат.часть дальше.

Comment: а, ну да, еще заголовок подредактировал, теперь он такой function BobJenkinsHash64(const k: TBytes; length, level: Integer): UInt64;

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем так: Нам надо, чтобы pb[20] было 20-м интом в наших данных. Тогда:

```
type 
  AUInt64: array[0..0] of UInt64; 
  PAUInt64: ^AUInt64;
// x := BobJenkinsHash64(@DATA, DATAlength, 1);
function BobJenkinsHash64(k: PAUInt64; length, level: Integer): UInt64;
var
  pd: PAUInt64; // ссылка на нулевой элемент
  a, b, c, len: UInt64;
begin
  len := length;
  a := level;
  b := level;
  c := $9e3779b97f4a7c13;
  pd := k; // нулевой элемент AUInt64
```

тогда pd[20] будет обращением к 21 элементу массива типа AUInt64.

Далее, увеличение значения указателя:

```
pd := Pointer(Cardinal(Addr(pd))+20*sizeof(Int64)); // Числовое значение указателя + 20 * (размер инт64 = 8 байт)
```

Пока больше не наблюдаю, доложите результат, там подумаем)

---

ЗЫ: По хорошему вам надо объявить массив юинтов, заполнить его и передать в функцию (тогда вместо `k: PAUInt64` будет `var Data: AUInt64;`)

---

*Ну раз уж вопрос закрыли, добавлю только что добитую версию для delphi7*

```
type
  UInt64 = 0..9223372036854775807;
  AByte = array[0..0] of Byte;
  PAByte = ^AByte;

procedure mix64(var a, b, c: UInt64);
function BobJenkinsHash64(var pb: PChar; length, level: Integer): UInt64;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure mix64(var a, b, c: UInt64);
 begin
  Dec(a, b); Dec(a, c); a := a xor (c shr 43);
  Dec(b, c); Dec(b, a); b := b xor (a shl  9);
  Dec(c, a); Dec(c, b); c := c xor (b shr  8);
  Dec(a, b); Dec(a, c); a := a xor (c shr 38);
  Dec(b, c); Dec(b, a); b := b xor (a shl 23);
  Dec(c, a); Dec(c, b); c := c xor (b shr  5);
  Dec(a, b); Dec(a, c); a := a xor (c shr 35);
  Dec(b, c); Dec(b, a); b := b xor (a shl 49);
  Dec(c, a); Dec(c, b); c := c xor (b shr 11);
  Dec(a, b); Dec(a, c); a := a xor (c shr 12);
  Dec(b, c); Dec(b, a); b := b xor (a shl 18);
  Dec(c, a); Dec(c, b); c := c xor (b shr 22);
end;

function BobJenkinsHash64(var pb: PChar; length, level: Integer): UInt64;
var
  a, b, c: UInt64;
  i, ishl: integer;
  d: PAByte;
begin
  a := level;
  b := level;
  c := 712544676207699905;
  d := @pb[0];
  i := 0;
  if (length > 24) then
    repeat
      a := a + d[i   ] + (d[i+ 1] * $10) + (d[i+ 2] * $100) + (d[i+ 3] * $1000) + (d[i+ 4] * $10000) + (d[i+ 5] * $100000) + (d[i+ 6] * $1000000) + (d[i+ 7] * $10000000);
      b := b + d[i+ 8] + (d[i+ 9] * $10) + (d[i+10] * $100) + (d[i+11] * $1000) + (d[i+12] * $10000) + (d[i+13] * $100000) + (d[i+14] * $1000000) + (d[i+15] * $10000000);
      c := c + d[i+16] + (d[i+17] * $10) + (d[i+18] * $100) + (d[i+19] * $1000) + (d[i+20] * $10000) + (d[i+21] * $100000) + (d[i+22] * $1000000) + (d[i+23] * $10000000);
      mix64(a, b, c);
      inc(i, 24);
      until i+24 >= length;

  Inc(c, length);

  if (i < length) then
    begin

    ishl := ((length - i) mod 8) * 8; // ex.: length = 275, i = 264, ishl = 3 * 8 = 24;
    if (length - i > 16) then
      Inc(c, (d[length-1] shl ishl))
      else if (length - i > 8) then
      Inc(b, (d[length-1] shl ishl))
      else
      Inc(a, (d[length-1] shl ishl));
  end;

  mix64(a, b, c);
  Result := c;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyMSG: PChar;
begin
  MyMSG := PChar(Memo1.Text);
  Edit2.Text := IntToStr(BobJenkinsHash64(MyMSG, Length(Memo1.Text) * SizeOf(MyMSG[1]), 13));
end;
end.
```

Comment: Дельфи не знаю. Но, идея тут понятна. В оригинале передается массив 32-битных констант, по нему прыгают и делают битовые сдвиги их значений.

Автор видимо передает его же, но в функции рассматривает как массив 64-х битных значений. Отсюда и описываемые им симптомы. Т.е. ему надо править **вызывающую** часть.

Comment: <i>В оригинале передается массив 32-битных констант</i>

М-м-м-м.. Неверно

<pre>ub8 hash( k, length, level)
register ub1 *k;        /* the key */
register ub8  length;   /* the length of the key */
register ub8  level;    /* the previous hash, or an arbitrary value */</pre>
Это исходный код. Если поглядеть чуть повыше, то можно найти, что ub1 = unsigned char, т.е. однобайтная переменная, а, следовательно, k - указатель на массив байтов, а не int32 или int64...

Comment: Посмотрел исходник на Си. Передается ключ (массив байт, рассматриваются как беззнаковые) длиной length байт. Собственно его хэш и считаем.

Однозначно, у автора **использование pd[i] - ошибка. Надо брать pb[i] (без знака)** присваивать его 64-разрядной переменной (целое без знака), его сдвигать и результат добавлять к вычисляемой сумме.

Как описать это на Дельфи - не знаю.

Comment: @avp, @gecube, спасибо, я понял в чем прикол алгоритма)) Ща перепишу)

Comment: но ведь я вроде так и сделал: pd ссылается на то же место что и pb, директива absolute при объявлении pd...

Comment: Ну тут-то и проблема. Каждый элемент массива pd[], размещенного на том же месте, что и массив pb[] **содержит 8 смежных pb[i]**. Запись pb := @(k[0]); в Дельфи реально изменит такой маппинг ?

Comment: Вообще мне библиотеки сказали, 

1) UInt64 - диапазон 0..1 (а в XE2 явно прописано type UInt64 = Int64, т.е. "заглушка"). 

2) `pb := @(k[0]);` - технически верно (первый байт = первый байт), но соотношение size(pd)/size(pd)=8 это не изменит.

Answer (score 0):

WTF!?

```
const k; length, level: Integer
^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^
pb: PByte;
pd: PUInt64 absolute pb;
pb := @k; {т.е. pb и pd ссылаются на одну область памяти, т.е. на 32-битное число k!?!?!?}
```

И Вы часом `pb` и `pd` в программе не путаете!?

Comment: Похоже для 64-битного хэща константа k  д.б. не 32 а 64-разрядное число.

Кстати, просветите,  что означает  в Дельфи выражение типа (pd[20] shl 40) ?

Comment: pd - по идее должен был быть массив байтов чего-то там. Мы сдвигаем 20-й элемент вправо на 40 битовых разрядов. В случае преобразования из байтовой переменной в int64 я это могу понять. Но если сдвигать 64-битное число - фигня какая-то получается. ИМХО.

<i> Похоже для 64-битного хэща константа k д.б. не 32 а 64-разрядное число.</i>
Да, это тоже я имел в виду.

Comment: Утверждаюсь во мнении, что перепутаны переменные `pb` и `pd`

Comment: <a href="http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/Shl.php.html">SHL</a>, побитовый сдвиг влево. Аналог X<<N в php.

Comment: Т.е. (pd[20] shl 40) означает, что в 64-битном числе биты начиная с 20-го сдвигаются на 40 бит влево ??? Они как нумеруются ? Нулевой (младший) самый правый ? И что будет с битами левее 20-го ? $X<<N в php это то же, что и в Си ? (Но в Си мы двигаем все биты числа).

Comment: Нумерация битов вообще к делу отношения не имеет. Странно, но Вы то точно должны знать как это все работает. 
X SHL Y = X << Y = X * 2^Y (ес-но с обрезанием всех вышедших за разрядную сетку битов).
X SHR Y = X >> Y = X / (2^Y)
^ в данном случае - возведение в степень.

Comment: К сожалению, это мой последний комментарий (лимит-с !). Выносить свое любопытство в ответ, считаю нехорошо. 

Не мог просто представить, зачем сдвигать биты в байте на 40. 

Наверное 64-битное pd должно "ложиться" на 20-й байт pb и эти 64 бита сдвигаются. Как это правильно записать в Дельфи ? Т.е. байты pb должны начинаться с k. Но тогда k должно быть (судя по индексам pb) не одним (пусть даже 64-х разрядным числом), а массивом чисел, иначе ничего не сложится.

Comment: Аааа какого хрена, удаляю предыдущее `>_<`. 

`@k` - это указатель, а не наоборот. то есть `pb := @k` вообще смысла не имеет(присвоение pb *значения* указателя на константу). В предыдущем примере правильно так:

    k: DWORD; ...
      ...
      pd: array[0..0] of UInt64;
      ...
      pd := Pointer(k);

@avp, k указывает на участок памяти. pd[20] (`Pointer(k+20*sizeof(UInt64))`) - 20-й элемент (в нашем случае int64). Но у автора перепутаны индексы и указатели, вот. ЗЫ: лимит 4 =)

Comment: Еще раз повторюсь, но на входе у нас должен быть массив байтов. А не массив инт64. Иначе нужно алгоритм модифицировать. Сдвига на 20 битов нет. Это не очень осмысленно. А сдвиг на кратное восьми - очень даже. Оно как бы располагает байт из исходного массива как опреднленный байт 64-битного числа промежуточного результата.